# ES6 String.prototype.normalize versus W3C normalization

Tags: javascript, unicode, utf-8, normalization, unicode-normalization

I understand that ES6 will have a new function that will do a utf-8 normalization of a string (using the 'NFC' form for example).

Reading http://www.unicode.org/faq/normalization.html, I saw this FAQ :

> Q: What is the difference is between W3C normalization and Unicode
>   normalization?
>
> A: Unicode normalization comes in 4 flavors: C, D, KC, KD. It is C
>   that is relevant for W3C normalization. W3C normalization also treats
>   character references (&#nnnn;) as equivalent to characters. For
>   example, the text string "a&#xnnnn;" (where nnnn = "0301") is
>   Unicode-normalized since it consists only of ASCII characters, but it
>   is not W3C-normalized, since it contains a representation of a
>   combining acute accent with "a", and in normalization form C, that
>   should have been normalized to U+00E1.

does that mean that we will need to replace all occurrences of &#xnnnn; by their utf8 equivalents before calling normalize('nfc') ?

or will there be some sort of normalize('w3c') that will help consider a letter combined with an accent via the ascii "&#xnnnn;" equivalent to its normalized form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your javascript executes the &...; is already gone, if you handle the DOM.
The only time you would see that is if you download and html somehow.
And, anyway, converting the &...; to the proper character is un-escaping, not normalization.
So you would have to un-escape, then normalize.